# Convert a 2 y-axes bar chart to 2 x-axes bar chart with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have the bar chart with the 2 `y-axes` below and I would like to convert it to a horizontal 2 `x-axes` bar chart.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

x <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
y1 <- c(20, 14, 25, 16, 18, 22, 19, 15, 12, 16, 14, 17)/10
y2 <- c(19, 14, 22, 14, 16, 19, 15, 14, 10, 12, 12, 16)
data <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

data$x <- factor(data$x, levels = data[["x"]])

ay <- list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = "Right Hand Axis"
)

p <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(data, x = ~x, y = ~y1, name = 'Primary Product (LHS)', 
           marker = list(color = 'rgb(49,130,189)'), offsetgroup = 1) %>%
  add_bars(data, x = ~x, y = ~y2, name = 'Secondary Product (RHS)', 
           marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)'), yaxis = "y2", offsetgroup = 2) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = ay,
         xaxis = list(title = "Time Period", tickangle = -45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Left Hand Axis"),
         margin = list(b = 100),
         barmode = 'group',
         legend = list(x = 1.1, y = 1))

p
```

and here is my attempt

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

x <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
y1 <- c(20, 14, 25, 16, 18, 22, 19, 15, 12, 16, 14, 17)/10
y2 <- c(19, 14, 22, 14, 16, 19, 15, 14, 10, 12, 12, 16)
data <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

data$x <- factor(data$x, levels = data[["x"]])

ax <- list(
  overlaying = "x",
  side = "bottom",
  title = "Bottom Hand Axis"
)

p <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(data, y = ~x, x = ~y1, name = 'Primary Product (LHS)', 
           marker = list(color = 'rgb(49,130,189)'), offsetgroup = 1) %>%
  add_bars(data, y = ~x, x = ~y2, name = 'Secondary Product (RHS)', 
           marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)'), yaxis = "y2", offsetgroup = 2) %>%
  layout(xaxis2 = ax,
         yaxis = list(title = "Time Period", tickangle = -45),
         xaxis = list(title = "Top Hand Axis"),
         margin = list(b = 100),
         barmode = 'group',
         legend = list(x = 1.1, y = 1))

p
```

Comment: You can pass `orientation = 'h'` in `add_bars()`, though you'll need to go reconfigure quite a bit of the axis stuff so it's not a mess. Also double axes are not great; consider facetting or another approach.

Comment: I know but there must be a way to reverse all of them